# Help to identify old Firefighter badge

Tags: war

[image: **Large metal badge with enamel logo, with five birds on it .**]

arge metal badge with enamel logo, with five birds on it

Answer (score 3):

The coat-of-arms is that of the Austrian state of [Lower Austria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Austria); [another source](http://www.ngw.nl/heraldrywiki/index.php?title=Nieder%C3%B6sterreich) says that *"the arms were officially granted in 1920"* (the mural crown is usually employed by republics to replace monarchic crowns), placing it sometime between that date and 1938.
EDIT: [Here](https://www.militaria-agent.com/catalog/AUSTRIA_2ND_REPUBLIC_LOWER_AUSTRIA_4_FIREFIGHTER_BADGES_MERIT_MEDAL_FOR_25_AND_50_YEARS_ALSO_2_OTHER_ENAMELED_MEDALS_4_DIFFERENT.html)'s someone selling that same badge and dating it as "Second Austrian Republic", that is, anytime since 1945.